# React component not updating after redux store is populated

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm relatively new to react and am trying to use redux as the central state store for my application. My issue is that when I fetch data and after the data is successfully added to the store, my component is not updating. In the example below, `loading` is always displayed on the page. the call to `store.getState().schools` returns an array of 3 objects as verified by the `console.log` statement. How can I overcome this?

Component:

```
export default class SchoolsContainer extends Component {
    displayName = SchoolsContainer.name;

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        axios.get('https://localhost:44398/api/schools')
            .then(response => {
                response.data.forEach(school => {
                    store.dispatch(addSchool(school));
                })
                console.log(store.getState().schools);
                console.log(this.props.schools);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("err", err);
            });
    };

    render(){
        if(this.props.schools != null && this.props.schools.length > 0) {
            return <Schools schools={store.getState().schools} />
        }
        else{
            return (<div>loading</div>);
        }
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
      schools: state.schools
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SchoolsContainer);
```

Comment: Your class needs to be connected to redux with connect()

Comment: @EranGoldin I've updated my post as suggested (I believe that's the way to do it) and the same behavior is occurring

Comment: && store.getState().length doesn't look right. i think you are missing a schools property in this condition? store.getState().schools.length>0. And you should access the state object through component props instead of store object

Comment: @jure accessing the `schools` via props instead of directly from the redux store was the issue. if youd like to post this as an answer, ill gladly accept and yes there was a schools property missing from the if check as well

Comment: @GregH nice you have it working, I posted the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that your exported component should be connected to the redux store

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SchoolsContainer);
```

And then you can access the redux state object through the component props instead of directly referencing the store object, like this:

```
if(this.props.schools != null && this.props.schools.length > 0) {
        return <Schools schools={this.props.schools} />
    }
```